# How can I replace a class file in jar files?

Tags: java, jar

A coworker of mine wrote a class. His class uses my class. Rather than tell the JVM where my class lives every time his class is compiled, he packaged both classes into a jar file that I can run like so: `java -jar hisclass.jar`

Now I have decided to make changes to my class. Therefore, since my class was precompiled into  his jar, his class (which I still need to use) uses my old class. My coworker left, and I don't know how he packaged everything into a jar file for me to use.

Now, when I try `java -jar hisclass.jar`, when his class calls my class, it calls an old version of my class which produces an error, as that old version of my class no longer works correctly. Could anyone help me recompile his class into a jar or just update the one I have?

Comment: you could start with the oracle docs on jar: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html

Comment: There's a lot of information missing here.  Does the combined jar contain only his class and yours, or are other dependencies included? Do you have the source code for his class? Can you recompile his class?  Are you using an IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, the jar has many other files. I have his source code and can recompile it. I'm using PuTTY onto a linux machine but I could open the whole project on Eclipse as well (it is stored in an SVN repository).

Comment: You need to set up a real IDE project to manage the source and dependencies.  Then these problems will go away as your class and his just become parts of (and are managed within) a larger project.  You shouldn't be tearing apart jars.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should clarify. I am using Eclipse primarily for my Java development. The class I wrote that I need to update in the jar was developed in Eclipse. I am simply using PuTTY to work on the server on which I have other code running (JavaScript, HTML, etc) and from which I call the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse i think it should be enough to export your code as jar file.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse/

So basically you get the old jar, extract, load as project in eclipse and export as jar file.
And you're done.

Comment: Thank you. I just exported his source code as a jar in eclipse and everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

- for spcified class file

```sh
jar -uvf0 <YOUR_JAR_NAME>.jar io/some/package/service/TestService.class
```

- for whole dir.

```sh
jar -uvf0 <YOUR_JAR_NAME>.jar io/some/package/service/
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you can get away with it or not, but you might want to just try compiling your class to a jar file, then opening his jar file up in some compression agent like WinRAR, and simply overwriting the old jar file contained in his jar file with your newly compiled version.  A better way  (if he class isnt obfuscated) would be to open his jar file in a Java IDE, and create a new project from it. Then reference the the project you created from his jar file in your project in the same IDE. This way, you can make changes to both in the same environment, and compiling the code after changes will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your .jar file and change your compiled classes.